# syntax error "'=' expected near '_APPNAME" doesn't make sense

Tags: lua, syntax-error, coronasdk

This is the code that I have:

main.lua :

```
-- start the app, declare some variables, setup the player save file. 

-- APP OPTIONS
_APPNAME = "The Square Cannon"
_FONT = "Tolo"

--  OTHER UPGRADES

_SHOWADS = TRUE

-- CONSTANT VALUES
_CX = display.contentWidth*0.5 --center of the screeen going horizontally
_CY = display.contentHeight*0.5 --center of the screem going vertically
_CW = display.contentWidth -- width of the screen
_CH = display.contentHeight -- height of the screen
_T = display.screenOriginY -- top of the screen
_L = display.screenOriginX -- left of the screen
_R = display.viewableContentWidth - _L -- right of the screen
_B = display.viewableContentHeight - _T -- bottom of the screen

-- hide the status bar
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- include composer
local composer = require "composer"

-- include load/save library from coronarob
loadsave = require("loadsave")

-- load some audio
_BACKGROUNDMUSIC = audio.loadStream("THESQUARECANNON\audio\IceFLow" , "THESQUARECANNON\audio\FreeInstrumental")
--{
    --load some sound effects, when created
--}

-- set up a saved file for our user
user = loadsave.loadTable("user.json")
if (user == nil) then
    user = {}
    user.playsound = true
    loadsave.saveTable(user, "user.json")
end

composer.gotoScene("scene_menu")
```

and this is the error that I am getting:

```
main.lua:5: '=' expected near "'_APPNAME'"
```

What could possibly be wrong? I have an `=` sign exactly where it needs to be, although the console still says that I need one.

Comment: Are `config.lua`, `main.lua`, and `scene_menu.lua` three separate files? I presume so judging from the error messages that refer to two of those file names. That's not at all clear given the way you've formatted your code. I'll edit it for your; feel free to revert my edit if it's incorrect.

Comment: My edits may have thrown off some line numbers. `<eof>` means end of file. If I delete the trailing comma in `config.lua`, the `unexpected symbol near '<eof>'` error goes away.

Comment: For the `config.lua` error, get rid of the comma after the very last closing `}` and that should get rid of your error. Not sure as far as the `main.lua` code goes; it looks right to me. Have you posted all of the contents of the file?

Comment: thank you @DavisDude, your advice fixed the second error. However I am still receiving the first error, "main.lua:5: '=' expected near '_APPNAME'"

Comment: And thank you @KeithThompson for clarifying my code.

Comment: When I copy-and-paste your code into `main.lua` and run `lua main.lua`, I don't get that error. I do get an error about an invalid escape sequence; you need to double the backslashes. It's likely that the your code differs from what you've shown us. Try this: copy-and-paste your code from this web page into a file, and run the `lua` command on that file.

Comment: I bet the problem is on line 1 of `main.lua`, which you don't seem to have shown us. You may have edited it out because you thought it was irrelevant, but it seems that the part you edited out was the *most* relevant part.

Comment: @TannerSwett line one of main.lua is simply `--main.lua`. I used it just to make sure what class I'm working in. I believe it was Keith Thompson who edited my code to make it more relevant, and in doing so he took out the first line of that class and made it a sort of header

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code that isn't shown? I count  3 left brackets and only 2 right brackets. 
You have another typo.

```
_CX = display.contentWIdth*0.5 -
```

Should be

```
_CX = display.contentWidth*0.5 -
```

Comment: yes i do, however they are in other classes and i believe they are irrelevant to this in particular. i just put another right bracket and it didn't seem to fix anything

Comment: @CameronLee: It's very relevant. The code you showed us is invalid. If you're saying that the errors in the code you showed us aren't the problem, then it must be in some code you haven't shown us. Please update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

That error message is due to the presence of `config.lua` in the file.

Changing `config.lua` to `-- config.lua` will give you a different message, because the brackets are not balanced.

Comment: i simply put config.lua there as a file name, however i did as you said and am receiving a new error: "config.lua:14: unexpected symbol near '<eof>'" where like 14 would be the new third closing bracket.